# Error installing a content package on a fresh install of Sitecore 8.1 Update 3

Tags: packages

I am installing content under \sitecore\content\home on a fresh install and I am getting the following error. I made sure all the templates needed are in place.

```
ManagedPoolThread #9 10:57:28 ERROR Installation failed: System.AggregateException: One or more exceptions occurred while processing the subscribers to the 'item:renamed' event.
   at Sitecore.Events.Event.EventSubscribers.RaiseEvent(String eventName, Object[] parameters, EventResult result)
   at Sitecore.Events.Event.RaiseEvent(String eventName, Object[] parameters)
   at Sitecore.Events.Event.RaiseItemSaved(Object sender, ItemSavedEventArgs args)
   at System.EventHandler`1.Invoke(Object sender, TEventArgs e)
   at Sitecore.Data.Engines.EngineCommand`2.RaiseEvent[TArgs](EventHandler`1 handlers, Func`2 argsCreator)
   at Sitecore.Data.Engines.EngineCommand`2.Execute()
   at Sitecore.Data.Engines.DataEngine.SaveItem(Item item)
   at Sitecore.Data.Managers.ItemProvider.SaveItem(Item item)
   at Sitecore.Data.Managers.PipelineBasedItemProvider.ExecuteAndReturnResult[TArgs,TResult](String pipelineName, String pipelineDomain, Func`1 pipelineArgsCreator, Func`1 fallbackResult)
   at Sitecore.Data.Managers.PipelineBasedItemProvider.SaveItem(Item item)
   at Sitecore.Data.Items.ItemEditing.AcceptChanges(Boolean updateStatistics, Boolean silent)
   at Sitecore.Install.Items.ItemInstaller.UpdateItemDefinition(Item targetItem, XmlVersionParser parser)
   at Sitecore.Install.Items.ItemInstaller.GetVersionInstallMode(PackageEntry entry, ItemReference reference, XmlVersionParser parser, ItemInstallerContext context, Boolean& removeVersions)
   at Sitecore.Install.Items.ItemInstaller.InstallEntry(PackageEntry entry)
   at Sitecore.Install.Items.ItemInstaller.Flush()
   at Sitecore.Install.Framework.SinkDispatcher.Flush()
   at Sitecore.Install.Utils.EntrySorter.Flush()
   at Sitecore.Install.Zip.PackageReader.Populate(ISink`1 sink)
   at Sitecore.Install.Utils.EntrySorter.Populate(ISink`1 sink)
   at Sitecore.Install.Installer.InstallPackage(String path, Boolean registerInstallation, ISource`1 source, IProcessingContext context)
   at Sitecore.Install.Installer.InstallPackage(String path, IProcessingContext context)
   at Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Install.Dialogs.InstallPackage.InstallPackageForm.AsyncHelper.<Install>b__4()
   at Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Install.Dialogs.InstallPackage.InstallPackageForm.AsyncHelper.CatchExceptions(ThreadStart start)
```

Comment: other packages are installing fine, its just the items which are supposed to go under home.

Comment: Can you manually add and rename items under the home node?

Comment: Yes, I am able to add, rename and delete. I am trying to pull content from one env and push to the new local install. I feel that this might me a few specific items not sure yet.

Comment: Do you have Coveo installed ? I had something similar when Coveo was  not correctly installed

Answer (score 6):

This is due to the Sitecore.Analytics.config. In the config file, you have the handler

```xml
<handler type="Sitecore.Analytics.Data.Items.ItemEventHandler, Sitecore.Analytics" method="OnItemSaved"/>
```

This is triggered when the item is being saved. So, the event `item:renamed` will trigger the event `item:saved`, hence executing the above handler.

So, in order to fix the issue, you need to make sure that mongoDB service is running.

If you are not using the xDB, you need to disable it in the Sitecore.Xdb.config as shown below:

Change

```xml
<setting name="Xdb.Enabled" value="true" />
```

to

```xml
<setting name="Xdb.Enabled" value="false" />
```

And change

```xml
 <setting name="Xdb.Tracking.Enabled" value="true" />
```

to

```xml
 <setting name="Xdb.Tracking.Enabled" value="false" />
```

Comment: Actually, `Xdb.Tracking.Enabled` doesn't have to do with database communication, so it should be safe to leave that with `true`.

Comment: tried it, its doesnt seem to help.

Comment: other packages are installing fine, its just the items which are supposed to go under home.

Comment: Does commenting the handler in the Sitecore Analytics allows the package to be installed?

Answer (score 3):

Do you have mongodb installed and its connection strings configured? There is a known issue with package installs not completing when mongodb is not configured for xDB.

Comment: Mongo is installed and configured

Answer (score 0):

Could be something in the package that's violating the allowed item name in the sitecore config; check out the **ItemNameValidation** config setting and make it less aggressive, just in case.

Comment: Steve, this is a default install so the default item name validations should work. I checked the source and it has the same item name validations.

Comment: And thinking about it I'd just expect the items which were wrong to fail if this was the case rather than the whole package.

Comment: Is breaking the package down into smaller packages an option? Perhaps it might narrow down where it is falling over